# Debugging Git Bash key binding and git status color issues

Tags: git, bash, windows-8, ack

I installed ack via chocolately on my Windows 8 machine.  This caused the following issues with Git Bash:

1. Git output is no longer coloured.  I've confirmed this with `git status` and `git diff`, neither produce colour.  Other non-git commands do produce colour.  This only seems to affect output from git.
2. The Delete key now inserts a ~ character instead of deleting a character

I have tried to resolve the issue by doing the following:

1. Uninstalling ack
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling git bash
3. Removing all bash configuration files from the OS.  Then #2.

I have manually removed all ack depedencies that I could find.  I have also manually pruned my PATH variable to ensure that it is clean and that there are no path locations that could be holding any sort of bash configuration.

This isn't actually restricted to just Git Bash.  The colour issue has also affected PowerShell.

I've also noticed that running git diff now emits a warning: "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional".  This warning did not appear before.

I'm not sure what else to try?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean it has also affected powershell exactly? Do you mean the git status output when running git in powershell? Do other git commands have color? Does running `git status --color` make the colors work?

Comment: I've updated the question to include more details.  Yes, PowerShell exhibits the same colour issues - none of the git commands are output in colour.  `git status --color` didn't work - apparently it's not a valid option.

Comment: What does `echo "$TERM"` say? (Though I don't know how that would affect PowerShell, unless it fakes `$TERM` for git to look at or something.)

Comment: `echo "$TERM"` returns "dumb" in Git Bash and returns an empty string in PowerShell.

Comment: Does setting `TERM=cygwin` change anything about how git behaves? (That appears to be what it is set to here though I don't know what is setting that or why that setting makes sense.)

Comment: Yeh that fixed the issue in both Git Bash and PowerShell.  I've now updated the TERM system env variable and it's working great.  Thanks! 

Please post an answer summarising this and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment debugging to answer.

Apparently something went wrong with the `$TERM` variable in his environment.

Setting `$TERM` to `cygwin` (which is the value it has on my computer) may help (and seems to have done so).